# Recommended disk size for ULS logs in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, logging

We are building a new server farm and we are assigning a separate disk for SharePoint logs. Is there a recommended size for this disk please?

I have searched for a guidance but didn't find anything. We have used 20GB disk space in the past and that wasn't enough as it fills up quickly especially in the WFE's.

We have around 30k users, and a medium sized farm. With the default Diagnostic Logging settings, how much disk space should we be looking to allocate? 
Would 50GB be okay?

Answer (score 2):

There are two settings to limit the amount of logs:

- Number of days
- Size in GB

I am not a fan of keeping ULS-Logs forever if company-policy doesn't force me to do so. Most troubleshooting is done via ULS realtime-Log. I need the old logs only if i get a Correlation-ID from a user. Normally i try to keep 30 days. So i adjust the "size in GB" on how much logs are written every day. Then i add some extra space if verbose-logging needs to be enabled.

Another Recommendation: Enable NTFS-Compression on your Log-Folders. This reduces the required disk-space to ~30%. The "size in GB" parameter counts uncompressed logs. You could configure 100-120 for "size in GB" and store them on your 50GB log-partition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. We are using the default settings so it's 30 days but we have not set a 'maximum' gb.

Comment: Setting this limit avoids full disks, i.e. if you enable verbose-logging and forget to disable it. If you have a separate partition only for ULS-Logs, this might not affect your production. But i often see ULS, IIS and Usage-Logs (and other stuff like SearchIndex) on one partition.

Comment: I set 14 days and 3gb...however I find a .ibl file of 23gb. Why?

Comment: .ibl is not an ULS-Log. They have the filename extention .log. You should probably open a new question and post some content of the .ibl file. Maybe someone can help identify the source of the logfile.

Answer (score 1):

Size recommendation is depend upon, how to the SharePoint is usage. Following things you should consider before making any decision.

- What will be ULS logs level( default or Verbose)
- What is retention for ULS logs( how many Days)
- How much traffic on the SharePoint farm
- What type of operation in SharePoint.
- Ensure you Restrict Trace Log disk space usage
- Enable the Event log flooding protection.

I think 50Gb is enough for a medium farm( giving it is on all WFE in the farm). I would also say this, it is good idea to separate the Logs drive from the system drive as we noticed lot of issue in Past with combine(system drive and ULS logs on same drive).